# Explain why x+y --> k (a constant) as |x| and |y| become very large, for the equation x^3 + y^3 = 3xy.

Tags: calculus

I can calculate that k = -1, assuming that k is a constant, but I do not know how to explain why x + y --> k (a constant), which is what the question (homework) is asking.

Comment: Factor $x^3+y^3$ maybe? (There's a formula for the sum of two cubes) Not sure if it'll help

Comment: I don't actually think this tends to a limit as $|x|,|y|\to\infty$. You sure you read the question correctly?

Comment: This is a very good question. The equation defines the Folium of Descartes (see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes ). The problem consists in proving the given statement without making use of the "full theory" of this curve.

Comment: People who think it is unclear what is asked here should not have the right to close questions, high reputation notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce new orthogonal coordinates $u$, $v$ by means of 
$$x={u-v\over2},\quad y={u+v\over2}\ .$$
This amounts to a rotation by $45^\circ$ and a scaling. The equation then becomes
$$u^3-3u^2+3v^2+3uv^2=0$$
or
$$v^2={4\over 3(1+u)}-{(u-2)^2\over3}\ .$$
This shows that $|u|$ cannot get arbitrarily large, but $|v|$ can. The latter necessitates $$x+y=u\to-1\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Well...it's not an answer per se, but a hint about why this MIGHT be true or false...

Write $(x+y)^3$ (which should be a constant, if the claim is correct) to get 
$$
C = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3 xy^2 + y^3
$$
Now we're given that $3xy - x^3 - y^3 = 0$.

Adding that to the equation above gives
$$
C = 3xy + 3x^2 y + 3xy^2
$$
and factoring gives
$$
C  = 3xy (1 + x + y)
$$
If $x + y$ is constant, then this tells us that $3xy$ must also be approximately constant, and that pair of things doesn't seem to have a 
consistent solution for large $x$ and $y$.

So I think I agree with @AkivaWeinberger: I don't really believe the claim we're being asked to prove.

Answer (score 0):

$x^3+y^3=3xy$ is the equation of an algebraic curve in the plane $xy$

$x+y\to k$ as $|x|\to\infty \text{ and } |y| \to\infty$  means that the line $x+y=k$ is an asymptote of the algebraic curve

Factor the LHS of the equation

$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=3xy$

then solve for $x+y$

$x+y=\dfrac{3xy}{x^2-xy+y^2} $

As $x+y=k$ means $y=-x +k$ we know that as $x\to\infty$ then $y\to-\infty$

Then the RHS tends, as $x\to\infty$

$RHS\to \dfrac{3x(-x)}{x^2-x(-x)+x^2}\to\dfrac{-3x^2}{3x^2}\to -1$

Thus the asymptote has $x+y=-1$ as its equation

[image]